# Applying df.get() function to each row in pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

I am using Python Pandas DataFrame to look at a dataset for with information on different schools.

In one particular column `df['Grades_Offered']`, the data, which can be seen below, exists for each school in the dataframe. This is what the column in the csv looks like, with the gaps representing the different cells:

```
Grades_Offered
PK,K,1,2,3,4,5
PK,K,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
PK,K,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
9,10,11,12
```

I am trying to extract only the lowest grade from each row in this column. For example, I want to make a Lowest_Grade column in the dataframe where it would list out PK, PK, PK, 9 ... for the column I showed above.

I tried this:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
df['Grades_Offered'].values[i] = df.append(df['Grades_Offered'].get(0))
```

But it doesn't work. I am also trying to extract the highest grade as well, but hopefully with help on extracting the lowest grade I could manipulate that to get the highest grade.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `get()` returns values from a given column.

Comment: Is df['Grades_Offered'] a column of lists?

Comment: So it is from a CSV file, where Grades_Offered is a column and PK, K,1,2,3 exists in one cell, and there are many more cells with values from PK to 12 in them

Comment: looks like you need to `groupby()` the school and then use a function in `agg()` to get lowest grade for a school.   post some sample data and a solution can be provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it - you want to extract from a comma-delimited column.  If highest/lowest is defined as either end of this list, solution is as follows.

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""Grades_Offered
PK,K,1,2,3,4,5
PK,K,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
PK,K,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
9,10,11,12"""),sep="\s+")

df = df.assign(lowest_grade=df.Grades_Offered.apply(lambda s: s.split(",")[0]),
          highest_grade=df.Grades_Offered.apply(lambda s: s.split(",")[-1]))
```

|  | Grades_Offered | lowest_grade | highest_grade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | PK,K,1,2,3,4,5 | PK | 5 |
| 1 | PK,K,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 | PK | 8 |
| 2 | PK,K,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 | PK | 8 |
| 3 | 9,10,11,12 | 9 | 12 |